# Deploying Play Framework app in Heroku fails due to cannot find symbol error

Tags: java, maven, heroku, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.3

I am trying to deploy an app in Heroku using Play Framework 2.5 in Java and the twirl templates apparently cannot be found. I have already added the classes_managed folder needed into the build path so that the classes generated due to sbt compile can be found. What am I missing? The problem I find is due to the mvn install command, I am also using mvn compiler version 3.5.1. I appreciate any help, thank you in advance.

```
---------------------------------
remote:        [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
remote:        [INFO] ------------------------------------------------
------------------------
remote:        [INFO] Total time: 13.533 s
remote:        [INFO] Finished at: 2017-12-30T14:49:21+00:00  
remote:        [INFO] Final Memory: 29M/202M
remote:        [INFO] ------------------------------------------------
------------------------
remote:        [ERROR] Failed to execute goal 
org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-
compile) on project cdsstore: Compilation failure: Compilation 
failure:
remote:        [ERROR]/tmp/build_e0239abc024f292dddcba7732b9de514/app/controllers/CategoryListController.java:[51,27] cannot find symbol
remote:        [ERROR] symbol:   variable categorylist
remote:        [ERROR] location: class controllers.CategoryListController
remote:        [ERROR] /tmp/build_e0239abc024f292dddcba7732b9de514/app/controllers/CategoryListController.java:[75,27] cannot find symbol
remote:        [ERROR] symbol:   variable categorylist
remote:        [ERROR] location: class controllers.CategoryListController
remote:        [ERROR] /tmp/build_e0239abc024f292dddcba7732b9de514/app/controllers/CategoryListController.java:[113,27] cannot find symbol
remote:        [ERROR] symbol:   variable profile
remote:        [ERROR] location: class controllers.CategoryListController
remote:        [ERROR] /tmp/build_e0239abc024f292dddcba7732b9de514/app/controllers/ShoppingCartController.java:[67,39] package routes does not exist
```

Comment: Does the app compile when you run `mvn clean install` locally?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, at the end I solved this problem by removing the maven nature to the project and readding it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem by going into the project properties in eclipse, disabling the maven nature and then readding it again.